# About LazyConnection session timeout error when @ManyToOne mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When I mapped JPA Entity itself with @ManyToOne and fetch type with Lazy, the lazyconnectionException occurs if I save the entity.

First, I tried FetchType to Eager. But I heard that this option is bad at performance.

Second, I tried @Transactional Annotation at all classes which connected with my method.

The “Brand” table.

```
create table brand
(
  id bigint auto_increment
    primary key,
  parent_id bigint null,
  name varchar(20) not null,
  ticket_symbol varchar(20) null,
  display_status varchar(20) default 'SHOW' not null,
  call_brand_id varchar(45) null,
  talk_brand_id bigint null,
  create_date datetime null,
  create_by varchar(20) null,
  modify_date datetime null,
  modify_by varchar(20) null
);
```

And Brand table needs to mapped itself.It means Brand table can have parent table.So I write my Entity Code with this.

```
@Slf4j
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = “{tablename}", schema = “{scehmaname}")
public class TicketBrand extends BaseEntity {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private TicketBrand parentTicketBrand;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String ticketSymbol;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private DisplayStatus displayStatus;

    @Column
    private String callBrandId;

    @Column
    private Long talkBrandId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentTicketBrand")
    private List<TicketBrand> subTicketBrands;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "brand_agent_mapping",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "agent_id"))
    private Set<TicketAgent> agents;

    public TicketBrandView convertTicektBrandView() {
        return TicketBrandView.builder()
                .id(id)
                .parentBrandId(hasParentBrandId())
                .name(name)
                .ticketSymbol(ticketSymbol)
                .displayStatus(displayStatus)
                .callBrandId(callBrandId)
                .talkBrandId(talkBrandId)
                .agentCount(getAgentSize())
                .build();
    }

    public void addSubBrand(TicketBrand subBrand) {
        if (subTicketBrands == null) {
            subTicketBrands = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        subBrand.setParentTicketBrand(this);
        log.info(subTicketBrands.toString());

        subTicketBrands.add(subBrand);
    }

    public Long hasParentBrandId() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(parentTicketBrand).isPresent() ? parentTicketBrand.getId() : null;
    }

    public int getAgentSize() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(agents).isPresent() ? agents.size() : 0;
    }


}
```

At this situation, I call the “addSubBrand” function the exception throws, 
    TicketBrand.subTicketBrands, could not initialize proxy - no Session
        And I call this function like this.

```
 public void mappingBrand(Long ticketBrandId, Long parentBrandId) {
        TicketBrand ticketBrand = ticketBrandService.findBrandById(ticketBrandId);
        TicketBrand parentBrand = ticketBrandService.findBrandById(parentBrandId);
        parentBrand.addSubBrand(ticketBrand);
    }
```

Then LazyConnectionTimeoutError occurs.

Comment: do you have @Transactional on you service and DAO??

Comment: I use Repository interface, I use @Repository annotation.

Comment: Also I attatch @Transactional annotation at my service

Comment: can you try with @transactional at your service class as well as repository class??

Comment: yeap. I use transactional at my service class. Like this 

@Transactional
public class TicketService {

Comment: Please use @transactional at DAO also !!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is Resolved.

I set my database settings with Hikari Pool connection handler,

Then I connected to Multiple Hikari Pool's Database modules,

So I use @Primary annotation to One Pool, It makes problem.

I can't found the exact solution about this problem, but I solve this problem to split my project into pieces.